# Spark save dataframe metadata and reuse it

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I read a dataset with a lot of files (in my case from google cloud storage), `spark.read` works a lot of time before the first manipulation.
I'm not sure what it does but I guess it maps the files and sample them to infer the schema.

My question is, is there an option to save this metadata collected about the dataframe and reuse it in other work on the dataset.

-- UPDATE --

The data is arranged like this:

> gs://bucket-name/table_name/day=yyyymmdd/many_json_files

When I run: `df = spark.read.json("gs://bucket-name/table_name")` That's take a lot of time. I wish I could do the following:

```
df = spark.read.json("gs://bucket-name/table_name") 
df.saveMetadata("gs://bucket-name/table_name_metadata")
```

And in another session:

```
df = spark.read.metadata("gs://bucket-name/table_name_metadata").‌​json("gs://bucket-na‌​me/table_name") 
... 
<some df manipulation> 
...
```

Comment: You want to save the metadata or the schema ?

Comment: As I wrote, I'm not sure what it does. I want to save the time it take when I run the spark.read.json.
The data is arranged like this:
gs://bucket-name/table_name/day=yyyymmdd/many_json_files.
When I run:
df = spark.read.json("gs://bucket-name/table_name")

That's take a lot of time.
I wish I could do the following:
df = spark.read.json("gs://bucket-name/table_name")
df.saveMetadata("gs://bucket-name/table_name_metadata")

And in another session:
df = spark.read.metadata("gs://bucket-name/table_name_metadata").json("gs://bucket-name/table_name")
...
<some df manipulation>
...

Comment: @eliasah I'm not sure that the metadata is the right word for it, it just how I refer to it

Answer (score 1):

We just need infer the schema once and reuse it for the later files, if we have a lot of file which has the same schema.  like this.

```
val df0 = spark.read.json("first_file_we_wanna_spark_to_info.json")

val schema = df0.schema

// for other files
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json("donnot_info_schema.json")
```

Comment: Spark does nothing to map the partitions and the files in them?
Is it only the schema?

Comment: That's almost works for me but I still have problems with the partitions.
The partition field (day) is not available to query on it

Comment: Not sure what's your extract mean of partition field(day) mean. Perhaps you could elaborate more in your question. If day is only in the file name, then there are certain way you can add to the DataFrame after parse it.

Comment: The data is arranged like this:

gs://bucket-name/table_name/day=yyyymmdd/many_json_files

When I read the dataset, I have additional field that not exists inside the json called day and I can filter with it so the query is much smaller.

Comment: you can add to your DataFrame with `lit` function after you read it.